# Background-image not working in CSS3

Tags: html, css

Background-image isn't working in my CSS sheet. I did a Udemy course and everything in that course was working fine, but now that I'm attempting to create my own site using the same method it's not working. It's the exact same method.

And here is the CSS Code:

```
.header 
{
     background-image: url('img/battle_for_azeroth.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     height: 100vh;
     background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

the image url is probably wrong,thats the problem

Comment: Ignore the formatting please. Took forever to figure it out cause the rules for this site are frustrating.

Comment: get a help from http://docs.layerswp.com/doc/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-the-header/

Comment: That link didn't help. As you can see what I'm doing is exactly what's mentioned in the page.

Comment: @Buckyx55 What exactly not working for you? You are not able to see background image?

Comment: Most probably the background-image **url** is wrong. You should have console errors...

Comment: I have changed the directory url reference over 20 times and the background-image is still not appearing. I do not have any console errors. When I do a live launch through brackets, it doesn't work. When I launch the index.html file itself, it doesn't show either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what problem are you facing? Can you open up your web browser and get into the inspector tool? (press ctrl + shift + c in firefox)

When you're there, are you able to see a preview of your img? If it doesn't display your img, then the problem most likely lies in your background-image url.

Comment: I have changed the directory url reference over 20 times and the background-image is still not appearing. I do not have any console errors. When I do a live launch through brackets, it doesn't work. When I launch the index.html file itself, it doesn't show either.

Comment: Can you see the photo when you place your mouse over the code for preview in the console (press ctrl + shift + c in firefox)?
 
Does the parent element of header has any height? Try adding body, html { height: 100%; }